# How to reference a class inside a struct/class swift

Tags: swift, class, struct, reference

I am trying to outsource my functions (as I have a lot of them) to other files that are structs. But some of those functions reference variables that are inside my original class. So I am wondering how I can reference that class without getting an error like EXC_BAD_ACCESS or others.

Here is an example:

```
struct FirebaseAuthModel {
    
    var fb = FirebaseAuthModel()
    
    func signIn(email: String, password: String) {
        let auth = Auth.auth()
        auth.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)
        fb.signedIn = true
    }
}

class FirebaseModel: ObservableObject {    
    @Published var signedIn: Bool = false
    let auth = FirebaseAuthModel()
}
```

I want to do this so in my View I can do `fb.auth.signIn` so that the funcions are moreso sorted into different variables.

Comment: You have a double dependency between Model and Function which is not good from a design perspective. Looking at this particular example you don’t need Functions at all but otherwise if I understand the purpose of it I would instead make the functions in Functions static and send needed values as parameters. But again it’s not clear what you want to do.

Comment: Maybe you’re looking for “extensions” which would allow you to split code into different files but access the same properties on a class or struct?

Comment: I could use extension but that wouldn't completely achieve what I am trying to my knowledge. Does this other example I added in help at all?

Comment: @Joonaynay the example is fine, but unfortunately it is unclear if this is the result you expect, or if this it the initial situation and what you want to outsource where.